# Issues with Alert Boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

I have two functions i want on my on change event of a combo box, as below:

```
onchange="border_shaped();borderchk();"
```

I have two functions that check for a value and display a message box alert if matched.

The code works fine, apart from, whichever function is second in the onchange event, the alert box dissapears after being displayed.

So as above, the `borderchk();` function displays the alert message box for all of half a second then the form reloads. See below functions:

```
function borderchk()
{
    var bordercolour = document.designer.border_id.value;
    if (bordercolour == 145)
    {
        alert("Border Colour 145");
    }
    else if (bordercolour == 10100)
    {
        alert("Bordercolour 10100");
    }
}

function border_shaped()
{
    var sizerear1 = document.designer.size_back.value;
    var bordercolour1 = document.designer.border_id.value;
    if (sizerear1 == 10049 & bordercolour1 == 144)
    {
        alert("Border shaped");

        function borderchk();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please post HTML code as well

Comment: Now that I have formatted your code, it is clear to see there are a couple of syntax errors in your code. Hard to tell without the HTML, but the javascript is probably running, then erroring, jumping out of the onchange event and submitting the form.

Comment: you already called borderchk(); function inside border_shaped() function so please call only one in html onchange="return border_shaped();"

Comment: Sorry please disregard the  function borderchk(); in the other function this was just for testing to see if this would resolve the alert box from disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure why your form reloads without seeing the form HTML. I"m guessing it may be submitting but not sure.

Aside from that you have 3 errors in your javascript you posted:

1. This line `if (sizerear1 == 10049 & bordercolour1 == 144)`
   should be changed to this `if (sizerear1 == 10049 && bordercolour1 == 144)`
2. This line        `function borderchk();`
   should be changed to this        `borderchk();`
3. This is not really an error, but I would put all the numbers in double quotes since you are comparing them to STRINGS not NUMBERS. The values you get from form elements are STRINGS not NUMBERS, although == still seems to be working it might be safer to compare STRINGS to STRINGS

Comment: Hi, i tried the above but removing the function stops the script from working. I have added the two &&. Any ideas why the alert box is disappearing on the 2nd function?

Comment: maybe update the code above so we can see because calling a function with the reserved word "function" throws an error. function should only be used when defining a function, not calling it.